# Can I nudge a guide in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, guides

I'm trying to work with guides because I definitely see the advantage. But I'm having some issues with them snapping (and sticking) to content that I don't want them to align to.

Here's a screen cap of what I talking about.

[image: here's the problem]

I need these two columns to match in size, but the one on the right keeps snapping to the end of the word "upgrades".

I checked on Adobe's site, but their only advice for moving guides is to click and drag (or I guess you could type in the exact location you want when placing the guide in the first place).

Is there a method I can use that will allow me to be really precise with guides in Photoshop?

To clarify a bit more, I'm not trying to simply place guides an equal distance away from one another (although that will solve this particular issue) what I'm asking is for a way to nudge my guides pixel by pixel. Does this feature exist in photoshop or is my only option to click and drag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click/drag a new Marquis box (to snap along the edge of a guide). Use a keyboard arrow key and click once in a direction (moves the Marquis selection one pixel). Change to the Selection Tool and click/drag your Guide to the "marching ants" Marquis box.

Answer (score 1):

Look under the View menu on the top bar and look for Snap. If you uncheck this, guides will not snap.

Personally, I prefer it to snap. When dragging a guide, I hold down shift and it snaps to certain increments. When Snap is unchecked, this doesn't work and you will have to zoom in to be precise. Which is a lot slower.

In your situation, I'd move the Upgrades line out of the way, put my guide where I needed it, then reposition the text line accordingly.